# Python ldap3 reader call fails

Tags: python, ldap

So my first experience with ldap3 isn't going as planned. I cannot figure out why this isn't working...

Code example from http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/abstraction.html

```
s = Server('server')
c = Connection(s, user = 'username', password = 'password')
query = 'Department: Accounting'  # explained in next paragraph
person_reader = Reader(c, person, 'o=test', query)
person_reader.search()
```

That seems simple enough. But my code, which works fine for the Server and Connection calls, blows chunks in the Reader call. Here's the code snippet:

```
query = 'department: Security Risk'  
person_reader = Reader(c, person, 'OU=All Businesses', query)
```

and the fugly result

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
1 query = 'department: Security Risk'
----> 2 person_reader = Reader(c, person, 'OU=All Businesses', query)

C:\Users########\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ldap3\abstract\reader.py in init(self, connection, object_def, query, base, components_in_and, sub_tree, get_operational_attributes, controls)
79 self.base = base
80 self._components_in_and = components_in_and
---> 81 self.attributes = sorted([attr.name for attr in self._definition])
82 self.get_operational_attributes = get_operational_attributes
83 self.controls = controls

C:\Users##########\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ldap3\abstract\reader.py in (.0)
79 self.base = base
80 self._components_in_and = components_in_and
---> 81 self.attributes = sorted([attr.name for attr in self._definition])
82 self.get_operational_attributes = get_operational_attributes
83 self.controls = controls

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Per conda list:

```
ldap3                     1.0.4                    py35_0`
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you getting as far as calling `person_reader.search()`?  Your code sample says no.

Comment: FYI: I'm using Anaconda Python version 3.5.2

Comment: Also, what is `person`?  It appears to be undefined.

Comment: Nope. As soon as I create the reader object, I get an exception. All the types I'm feeding the call are string. And I'm not experienced with the debugger to debug through it.

Comment: person was a user id, but it has to be encoded as a object - which I missed. Now by LDAP server hates me. I get a new error: **LDAPSocketOpenError: socket connection error: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**  I'm beginning to take these error messages personally.

Comment: It looks like the LDAP server is configured to accept connections only from certain clients, or perhaps is behind a firewall.  You'll have to talk to the administrator of that server to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to Person() is:

> definition: the ObjectDef used by the Reader instance.

ref: http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/abstraction.html

You have to create an ObjectDef to pass in, this is not a userid.  This is a definition of the object type that should be read.  You might use it like:

```
person = ObjectDef(['person','user'], conn)
r = Reader(conn, person, base, query)
```

I don't have any experience passing the third argument to Person as anything but a fully qualified base DN.  So if ou=test is not a registered baseDn, this may not work in your LDAP(AD) instance.

Answer (score 0):

So after throwing everything at the wall and nothing sticking, I do what every developer w/o tools does - start from scratch and throw out everything you have been told. And the solution was:

remove the user authentication and make the call anonymously

Yes, even thought I had to jump through security hoops to get access to the call, no authentication was needed to use it. Yeah, we'll just be happy and move on. Don't dwell on it.